# Operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgresSQL ver 9.2. In this application I have two different databases. But the following query is executing in only one data base. I have compare pg_catelog functions in both databases, but all functions are same. 
    "SELECT now()+8"
Instead of this query, If I am using "SELECT (NOW() + interval '8 day')" its working fine in both databases. But there are around 1000 functions using the above feature. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using an outdated and unsupported Version?

Comment: Maybe there is a custom function `now()` in the first database? I cannot think of another reason why this should work. There never was support for adding integers to a timestamp.

Comment: What was your old database version? Something older than 8.3?

Comment: Version 9.2 hasn't changed in the last 18 hours.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264628

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for your feedback  [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264628/operator-does-not-exist-timestamp-with-time-zone-integer-in-postgresql) here we got Timstatmp, I need Date as return type

Comment: This is just a demo of how it is possible for it to fail in one database and not another.  You should check for user-created operators (you can use `\do` in psql) and see if this is actually the case.   I'm not suggesting you blindly add new operators.  But if you do want to, just change the type in the example to be the one you want it to be.